# jslint should watch only global variables

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jslint

I'm trying to use online lint from http://www.jslint.com/. I also tried using webstorm. I want to get only the global variables. however, my code is very long (about 30000 lines) and it scans only 1% of it.
Is there any way to use lint, or another tool to find only the global variables (the rest is not important for me).
My goal is to get all global variables attached to the window object.

Comment: Can you just run something like `for (value in window) { if (window.hasOwnProperty(value)) { console.log(value) } }` at some point after initialization? If it's JSLinted or, in this case, JSLintable, you could also grep the source for `var` (with some leeway for multiline declarations) and probably eyeball it fairly quickly.

Comment: This lines of code were exactly what I needed. If you'll write it as an answer I will accept it. I believe it could help more people. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad that's what you needed. I tried to turn it into a "real" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to run this script after the file's "initialized" (that is, if you're looking for what's on the global object after load), you can run something like this...

```
for (value in window) { 
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        if (console.log) console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that code can wait to add things to the global scope until it's called, so you could get more in the global context after more interaction with your code.

In a browser context, the `window` is the global object, so anything hanging off of it is in your global context.  In other contexts, it can be different -- in node, eg, [it's apparently `global`](http://www.hacksparrow.com/global-variables-in-node-js.html).

Allardice explains why you want `hasOwnProperty` in some detail [here](https://jslinterrors.com/the-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statement).  In brief, `hasOwnProperty` will limit you to properties on the object itself, without traipsing down the object's [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).  Even more briefly, using `hasOwnProperty` will cut out *some* of the cruft that wasn't added by your code to the object (in this case, the global `window` context).

Comment: This Was exactly what I needed and much simpler then lint!